# How to check if user has logged-in for the first time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, pug

I am using Node, Express, and MongoDB for my application. I am rendering Pug Template on server side and using Json Web Tokens for login.

I want to display a specific page when user logs in for the first time. Confused how to render it only one time.

Maybe adding a field like "accountStatus" and setting status to Active or Inactive will help?

Comment: As you said have a flag as `firstLogin` flag in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a `last_login_time` field on DB, it can also be used later for other logic in your app.

If the field is empty (or not exist) display the specific page.